# eval command function within ksh script is globbing when I don't want it to

Tags: bash, eval, ksh, evaluation, expression-evaluation

Consider the following ksh script "myquery.ksh"

```
#/usr/bin/env ksh -eu

PROCESS_TYP=$1
PROCESS_DT=$2

#Generate a query
makeSQL()
{
local numfiles=0
local query='SEL \\* FROM TABLE_1_'
case "$1" in
'ABC') query="${query}ABC" ; numfiles=1 ;;
'DEF') query="${query}DEF" ; numfiles=7 ;;
esac
query="${query}_V WHERE LOAD_DT='${2}';"
printf "$query\n"
eval $3="${query}"
eval $4=$numfiles 
return 0
}

makeSQL $PROCESS_TYP $PROCESS_DT qry num_files

printf "QUERY: $qry\n"
printf "NUMFILES: $num_files\n"
```

In the above code, the eval $3="${query}" statement never works correctly.  In all circumstances it seems to attempt to glob the "*" in the "local query="... statement.

```
./myquery.ksh ABC 2011-01-01
```

It always returns a message like this:

```
./myquery.ksh: line 17: \*: command not found
```

I am pretty sure this is my own user error with how I am applying eval in this situation but have tried nearly every alternate syntax construct for doing that eval $3 assignment but cannot manage to make this work.

I have tagged this as bash because I am pretty sure it would also behave identically there as well...

Answer (score 3):

Did you mean:

```
eval "$3=\$query"
eval "$4=\$numfiles"
```

Explanation: in your example you want to pass variable names to the function, and these variables are then set. So the statements should look like this:

```
qry=$query
num_files=$numfiles
```

Now the question is how to put these strings together. The left hand side comes from the arguments, for example `"$3"`. The right hand side contains a `$` that must *not* be interpreted too early. Therefore I wrote it as `\$`.

I always pass a single string to the `eval` command, since that gives me the most reliable results. Not `eval echo foo`, but `eval "echo foo"` instead.

Alternatively you could have written:

```
eval "$3"='$query'
eval "$3="'$'"query"
```

But the first form I suggested seems the simplest to me.